# Searching from multiple lists with elasticsearch

Tags: database, database-design, elasticsearch

We've got the following setup (simplified/changed):

MongoDB collection:
**Articles**

Redis lists:
**Today
Yesterday
This Week
This Month**

We receive new articles often and put them in the appropriate lists (a new article goes into 'today' 'this week' and 'this month' [redis lists contain id's to the mongodb collection]).

These lists can contain a lot of items ('this month' reaching into millions). 
These lists change rather often, articles disappear and reappear (business logic).

These lists have to be searchable (+beyonce -rihanna if you want to read news about beyonce but not about rihanna). Our first implementation (when the lists were small) was to simply index the entire Articles collection in Elastic and when searching a specific list we queried elastic with the keyword (+beyonce -rihanna) and all of the ids containing in the list. This worked for a few thousand entries, but as expected it doesn't scale very well.

We've currently thought of 2 ways to handle this:

- When indexing a new Article (in elastic) we reference all the lists
  it is in. So when querying for articles in a specific list our query
  contains the keyword (+beyonce -rihanna) and the list we're querying
  from (yesterday).
- Create multiple indexes in Elastic (1 for every redis list). When querying for an article we simply specify the index and the keyword.

Are either of those ways right? Or should we handle this case differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way is a good solution, IMO. You need to select the one that will best fit your business needs and be maintainable for your organization. Given the choice I would prefer the first option of referencing the list that the article is associated with in a single index for the following reasons:

- When articles move between the lists (today, yesterday, this week, this month), you will just need to update the list references. With the second approach, you would need to manage removing and adding the article to the appropriate indexes.
- If there is a use case to search across multiple lists at the same time (e.g today and yesterday) then you will lose the ranking, sorting and aggregation capabilities if the articles are in separate indexes. You will need to execute individual searches to the separate indexes and then rank, sort and aggregate the results yourself.

If you do decide to use the first option of a single index, I would recommend the use of filtered [Index Aliases](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) to manage the queries against the different lists. Using this approach you could create a single index, and then have aliases named today, yesterday, this_week and this_month that would automatically filter the articles based on that list name. And you would always have the main index itself to search against when you need to filter against more than one list.